# How to prevent XSS in jsp?

Tags: xss

This source is OWASP Webgoat 5.4 (jsp)

I want to filter <, >, script

so, i used to replaceAll

[image: 1]]

but,

it not work!

like this

[image: 2]

How to prevent XSS in this source?

Answer (score 0):

Would you please try this and let me know:

1. Add the JSTL taglib in your jsp as follows

   **<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn" %>**
2. use **fn:escapeXml**

   **${fn:escapeXml(searchName)}**